# Is it possible to make a SPARQL query over parsed triples in ARC2?

Tags: php, sparql

The [ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2) documentation is not really precise. It gives the two following examples:

First, parsing an RDF file:

```
$parser = ARC2::getRDFParser();
$parser->parse('http://example.com/foaf.ttl');
$triples = $parser->getTriples();
```

Second, making a SPARQL query on a datastore:

```
$q = 'SELECT ...';
$rows = $store->query($q, 'rows');
```

…but would it be possible to make a SPARQL query over the parsed `$triples` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC2 doesn't have an in-memory SPARQL processor, I'm afraid. The SPARQL engine is based on rewriting the query to SQL statements, which is why you need the Store component to run queries.

All you can do to make it a bit more smooth is to skip the parsing step and do a `$store->query('LOAD <URL>')` to directly import the triples into the store, but you still need the MySQL-backed store, unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, I'm honored Mr. Nowack created an account on StackOverflow to answer this question! I guess your status of ARC2 core developer makes your answer authoritative on the question ;) Also, thanks for having seen the unwritten question: yes, the MySQL store is mandatory. I'll add this to the wiki whenever I get some time.